# Что не так с RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Написал код, подгрузил базу, а RecyclerView не работает (неотображается как нужно). В чем может быть проблема? Переписал под новую базу AndroidX, но проблема осталась.
Код

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/greyfon"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не вижу закрывающей скобки у <RelativeLayout

Comment: вы полностью выложили xml?

Comment: просто код разметки плохо отформатирован был

Comment: invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @YuraIvanov, думаю, можно это даже в ответ написать)

Comment: А я думал - это простой вопрос, ответ на который я не знал по своей неопытности. А это получается в каждым может случиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо очистить кэш. `File-Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Согласно [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-projects.html#invalidate-cache) IDEA и в частности Android Studio кэширует огромное количество файлов. Иногда возникают конфликты. В частности визуальный редактор разметки не находит необходмые классы.

Не знаю подробностей реализации кэша в AS, со стороны выглядит так, что при смене `support` библиотек на `androidx` имена классов остаются прежними, но переезжают в другие пакеты. Механизм кэширования, видимо, этого не учитывает и возникает необходимость очистить кэш.

При очистке удаляется содержимое папки `.idea/libraries` в директории проекта (кроме прочего), при следующем открытии ide произойдет переиндексация и пересборка проекта, закэшируются правильные версии зависимостей.